# Angular JS Multiple Inputs in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Would there be any reason that multiple inputs aren't being passed from an Angular form to the controller. Either one of the inputs will submit. The problem is both of them won't submit in the same form.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="PostIndexCtrl" class="my-form">
        <input type='text' ng-model="entry.question_id" name="question_id" value="1">
        <input type='text' ng-model="entry.answer" name="answer"><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveEntry()">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the controller

```
.controller("PostIndexCtrl", function($scope, Post, $resource, $http) {

    Post.query(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    });

    var data = $resource('/api/answers/', {answer: '@answer', question_id: '@question_id'});

    $scope.saveEntry = function() {
        data.save($scope.entry);
    }

});
```

Comment: try initializing entry `$scope.entry = {}` in the controller

Comment: I learned AngularJs ignores hidden text inputs.

Comment: How is that related to your question?

Comment: Also did my comment solved your problem

Comment: Because the hidden input wasn't submitting because Angular ignores hidden input fields.